# htaccess send 404 if query string contains keyword

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, request.querystring

I'm seeing a lot of traffic which I suspect is probing for a flaw or exploit with the request format of

```
https://example.com/?testword
```

I figured while I look into this more I could save resources and disrupt or discourage these requests with a 404 or 500 response

I have tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)testword($|&) [NC]
RewriteRule https://example.com/ [L,R=404]
```

And some other variations on the Query string match but none seem to return 404 when testing. Other questions I have found look for query string values/pairs and rewrite them but no examples seem to exits for just a single value.

Comment: 404 isn't a redirect, so R=404 doesn't make sense, you can change that flag, with the F (403 forbidden) or G (410 gone)

Comment: also, maybe you want to give mod_security a look.

Comment: And your expression in the condition needs to be reversed. You want to redirect if the testword is present in the query string, so the negation ("!") does not make any sense in the condition.

Comment: @on8tom `R=404` makes perfect sense. The `R` flag is multi-purpose. It isn't only for external redirects. Behaviour is different when specifying a non-3xx HTTP status. (Just as you can use non-3xx status codes with the mod_alias `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` directives.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)testword($|&) [NC]
> RewriteRule https://example.com/ [L,R=404]
> ```

There are a few issues here:

- The *CondPattern* in your condition is negated (`!` prefix), so it's only successfull when the `testword` is *not* present in the query string.
- The `RewriteRule` directive is missing the *pattern* (first) argument (or *substitution* (second) argument depending on how you look at it). The `RewriteRule` directive matches against the URL-path only.
- When you specify a non-3xx status code for the `R` flag, the *substitution* is ignored. You should specify a single hyphen (`-`) to indicate *no substitution*.

To test that the whole-word "testword" exists *anywhere* in the query string, you can use the regex `\btestword\b` - where `\b` are *word boundaries*. Or maybe you simply want the regex `testword` - to match "testword" literally anywhere, including when it appears as part of another word? In comparison, the regex `(^|&)testword($|&)` would miss instances where "testword" appears as a URL parameter name.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \btestword\b [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ - [R=404]
```

This matches the homepage only (ie. empty URL-path). The `L` flag is not required when specifying a non-3xx return status, it is implied.

The `-` (second argument) indicates *no substitution*. As mentioned above, when specifying a non-3xx HTTP status, the *substitution* string is ignored anyway.

To test *any* URL-path then simply remove the `$` (end-of-string anchor) on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \btestword\b [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404]
```

If your homepage doesn't accept any query string parameters then you could simply reject the request (ie. 404 Not Found) when a query string is present. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^$ - [R=404]
```

Comment: Best answer MrWhite. 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^$ - [R=404]